# How to merge associations in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 4 models with these relationships:

```
class Summoner
 has_many :masteries
 has_many :stats
end

class Mastery
 belongs_to :summoner
 belongs_to :champion
end

class Stat
 belongs_to :summoner
 belongs_to :champion
end

class Champion
 has_many :masteries
 has_many :stats
end
```

I'm having a hard time to get around this, what I'm looking is to get every champion with a mastery and a stat object for a given summoner. The result would be something like this:

For summoner_id: 1

```
Champion1: { mastery: { summoner_id: 1, ... }, stat: { summoner_id: 1, ...} },
Champion2: { mastery: { summoner_id: 1, ... }, stat: { summoner_id: 1, ...} },
Champion3: { mastery: { summoner_id: 1, ... }, stat: { summoner_id: 1, ...} }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know if there is a single query for this, but the following might work (untested).

```
summoner = Summoner.find(1)
summoner_mastery_ids = summoner.masteries.pluck(:id)
summoner_stat_ids = summoner.stats.pluck(:id)

champions = Champion.includes(:masteries, :stats).where(masteries: {id: summoner_master_ids}, stats: {id: summoner_stat_ids})
```

Comment: you saved me from having a nightmare with this, thanks!